# How to combine several jQuery mouseover functions into one reusable mouseover function

Tags: jquery, css, json, html, d3.js

I created a map with D3 and added city names and plotted points on the map with the below json file (named city.json):

```
[
{"id":0,"name":"Damascus","lat":33.5131,"lon":36.2919,"graphic":"","marksLat":null,"marksLong":null},
{"id":1,"name":"Aleppo","lat":36.2167,"lon":37.1667,"graphic":"","marksLat":null,"marksLong":null},
{"id":2,"name":"Ar Raqqah","lat":35.95,"lon":39.0167,"graphic":"","marksLat":null,"marksLong":null},
{"id":3,"name":"","lat":null,"lon":null,"graphic":"graphic/star.png","marksLat":33.5131,"marksLong":36.2919}
]
```

The city points and city names shows on the map perfectly.  Each point and name was given an class name/number (using d3) so I can target each specific element.

I then added a mouseover and mouseout function, using jQuery, to the city points so I can display that point's latitude (lat) and Longitude (lon), information written in the json file.  Everything works great, when I mouseover the different points the correct information displays and when I mouseout it disappears. Below are my jQuery mouseover/out functions:

```
 $(".cityPoints1").mouseover(function() {
   d3.select("div.tooltip")
   .html([citiesData[1].lon, "&nbsp;" + citiesData[1].lat])
  .style("visibility", "visible")
  .style("top",  "100px")
  .style("left", "100px");
});
$(".cityPoints1").mouseout(function() {
  d3.select("div.tooltip")
  .html([citiesData[1].lon,  citiesData[1].lat])
  .style("visibility", "hidden");
});
$(".cityPoints2").mouseover(function() {
  d3.select("div.tooltip")
  .html([citiesData[2].lon,"&nbsp;" + citiesData[2].lat])
  .style("visibility", "visible")
  .style("top",  "100px")
  .style("left", "100px");
});
$(".cityPoints2").mouseout(function() {
  d3.select("div.tooltip")
  .html([citiesData[2].lon, citiesData[2].lat])
  .style("visibility", "hidden");
});
```

What I like to do and if it's possible is combine the mouseover functions into one function and the mouseout function into one function, and still display the correct information from the json file (when the user mouseover a point and the correct lat and long data will show).

Also I like the function to be expandable, able to accommodate newly added information (points) to the json file (can mouseover the newly added point and the correct data will display).

I hope this problem/question is clear and I really appreciate anyone's help with this issue.  Thanks in advance.  TonyT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you add a class to all the citypoints and just trigger off that?:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.citypoint").mouseover(function (e) {
      mouseOver_Event(e);        
    });    
});

function mouseOver_Event(e) {
      console.log(e); 
      var x = $(e.target).attr("id");
      alert(x);
}
```

I put it at this jsfiddle:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/2ppjf2f7/
```

If you can't add the class, and all the citypoints IDs are in the format citypointX you can use the jQuery startswith selector to make the trigger:

```
$('[id^=cityPoint]')
```

so the code would be like this (https://jsfiddle.net/a2466qhc/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('[id^=cityPoint]').mouseover(function (e) {
      mouseOver_Event(e);        
    });    
});

function mouseOver_Event(e) {
      console.log(e);
      var x = $(e.target).attr("id");
      alert(x);
}
```

On the jsFiddle you can check your console log (F12?) and see the different members of e

Comment: `$('[id^=cityPoint]').mouseover(mouseOver_Event)` is enough ^^

Comment: Wow...Thank you.  I like this concept but how do I include the json information.  When I mouseover the point how can i loop through and display the correct json information (lat and lon) that correspond with the city point ....or am I missing the point somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create variables for targeted elements instead of passing it to the DOM object like shown below

```
 var city1 = $('.cityPoints1');
```

then using event handler `.on` would trigger them

```
city1.on('mouseover mouseout', function(){
    city1.stop();
});
```

Hope it will help